# What are possible ways to refer to a particular (unique) real number that encodes a copy of a chosen large countable ordinal?

Tags: logic, ordinals

Let $E$ denote a particular (arbitrarily chosen, but fixed) method of representing ordinals as real numbers. Let $\alpha$ denote any large countable ordinal. Suppose that we want to refer to a particular real number $r$ that encodes the corresponding copy of $\alpha$ (assuming that $0 < r < 1$).

For example, consider the following “definition”:

> Let $\alpha=\omega_\omega^{\text{CK}}$. The number $r$ is equal to the minimal real number that encodes (according to the algorithm of $E$) any copy of $\alpha$ and is greater than the number $v = \pi - 3$ (that is, there does not exist another real number $w$ that encodes any copy of $\alpha$ by the algorithm of $E$ and satisfies the condition $v < w < r$ ).

Is this “definition” a mathematically correct definition of some particular (unique) real number $r$? If no, then what are possible options to refer to unique real numbers that encode copies of $\alpha$?

One option is using the notion of definability by formulas in a chosen formal language, so that some $i$-th formula will somehow correspond to the definition of $r$ that encodes a particular copy of $\alpha$. But are there any other options?

Comment: Why should there ever be a minimal such $r$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: but I also doubted that there existed such $r$, and this is why I emphasized that it was a “definition”, not a mathematically correct definition. But how else can we refer to such numbers (except involving the notion of definability by formulas)?

Comment: We can't, not in any reasonable way. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the "definition" you've given is not satisfactory. Regardless of what you mean by "encodes," you would need to justify the existence of a *minimal* real encoding each ordinal. SSequence's answer explains why this should strike you as *implausible* rather than plausible.

In fact, there is a precise sense in which what you want cannot be done. That is:

> There is no good way to assign to each countable ordinal a *specific* real "coding" that ordinal.

There's just no way around this.

*Of course, ZFC proves that there is a way to assign a real to each countable ordinal, that is, that there is an injection from $\omega_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The point is that the existence of such an injection doesn't say anything about the existence of such an injection which is in any way nice!*

---

Specifically, at the most abstract level you're asking for a "reasonably definable" injection from $\omega_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It turns out that such a thing probably doesn't exist *(the "probably" being a response to the inherent weaselliness of the phrase "reasonably definable")*. This is a consequence of results in [**descriptive set theory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory).

- First of all, the mere existence of an injection $\omega_1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ at all is not provable from ZF, so to do what you want you'll need to use the axiom of choice in a fundamental way. This tends to rule out the hope of anything so produced being "reasonably definable." And in particular, the [axiom of determinacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy) - which tends to make sets of reals behave incredibly *well* - proves that no such function exists. "Reasonably definable" objects tend to be compatible with AD, so this provides a further point of evidence.
- Now even within ZFC, this cannot be done in a [Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) way. Precisely, if $f:\omega_1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is an injection, then we cannot have $ran(f)$ and $\{\langle f(\alpha),f(\beta)\rangle: \alpha<\beta<\omega_1\}$ both be Borel. In fact, if the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) fails, there isn't even a Borel set of cardinality $\omega_1$ since the Borel sets have the perfect set property!
- In fact, under additional [set-theoretic hypotheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal), this can be pushed further - e.g. strong but still fairly reasonable large cardinal hypotheses imply that there is no projective well-ordering of a set of reals of ordertype $\omega_1$, and even no injection from $\omega_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is [definable from reals and ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L(R)).

Comment: I remember reading that we cannot precisely describe large countable ordinals, but we can define them in a suitable formal system (for example, by a formula based on ZFC). Does this mean that we can define such ordinals in some abstract form, but we cannot define any particular real number that encodes a copy of such ordinal?

Comment: Well it's going to depend on what you mean exactly by "define," but basically **yes**: it is in general easier to describe an ordinal than to describe any particular real "encoding" it. More generally, the following phenomenon is surprisingly common: a "simply definable" collection with no "simply definable" element. E.g. (i) the set of non-ordinal-definable reals is ordinal definable, (ii) the set $\{0^\#\}$ is $\Pi^1_2$ while the real $0^\#$ is $\Delta^1_3$, (iii) beyond the reals see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10413/definable-collections-without-definable-members-in-zf).

Comment: I am starting to experience some difficulty: if such real numbers are impossible to refer to, then I don't understand how [a function in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911530/is-it-possible-to-base-the-slow-growing-hierarchy-on-the-ordinal-defined-as-the) can be well-defined when the underlying ordinal does not correspond to a particular well-ordering. But if we have a particular well-ordering, then there exists a way to define a real number that encodes this well-ordering, and referring to such number is what I want...

Comment: @lyricallywicked I'm not sure what tension you're seeing. The whole point of that answer was that while specific reals coding $\alpha$ exist, there's no obvious way to pick out *one of them* as particularly nicely definable. You seem to be conflating the statement "there is a (= at least one) real coding $\alpha$" with "there is a 'specifically definable' real coding $\alpha$."

Comment: Basically: we have (i) for any countable ordinal $\alpha$, there is a (in fact, many) real encoding a copy of $\alpha$, and (ii) to each such real we can get an "$\alpha$-hierarchy" as per my other answer. However, (iii) at no point have we claimed that there is, to an arbitrary countable ordinal $\alpha$, a "best" (or "obvious" or "most natural" or ...) real coding a copy of $\alpha$. Point (iii) should be seen as *reinforcing* the issues re: copies/notations that I've pointed out in answers to your other questions: that we hit unavoidable non-uniqueness quite quickly.

Comment: Regarding (i) in the previous comment, I want to clarify: assuming that the method of coding well-orders as reals is fixed, are there finitely many or infinitely many reals encoding a copy of $\alpha$?

Comment: @lyricallywicked Infinitely many of course, indeed continuum many, for any reasonable notion of coding I can think of. E.g. there are continuum-many binary relations $R$ on $\omega$ such that $(\omega;R)\cong\alpha$ whenever $\alpha$ is an infinite ordinal.

Comment: Thank you, that was very important clarification. I am also guessing that there does not exist a particular well-order $R0$ such that $f_{R0}(x)$ dominates all other $f_{Ri}(x)$, where $Ri$ corresponds to a copy of $\alpha$. Because if such $R0$ existed, it would be possible to identify it as unique...

Comment: @lyricallywicked Yup, we can always do better than any given one. It's really as annoying as it could possibly be!

Answer (score 2):

First of all let us observe that a function $r:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ can be easily used to easily "store" all the information that a well-order relation with order-type $\alpha$ will have. For example, let $less:\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ denote the well-order relation (for a specific well-order of $\mathbb{N}$ with order-type $\alpha$). Now just define $r(x)=less(first(x),second(x))$, where $first:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $second:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are your usual inversion/extraction functions corresponding to a pairing function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

Regarding the sort of definition you put in quotes, I am sure this can't work. If, instead of $r:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, one works with a slightly different function, it is very easy to see. So first I will try to explain that example, and then a specific example for $r$. Define a function $I:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as:
$$I(x)=\left |\{n\,|\,(n<x) \,\,\land \,\,less(n,x)=1 \}\right |$$ 
Note that the bar sign means the number of elements in the given "finite" set.

Now suppose we are given two different functions $I_1(x)$ and $I_2(x)$ that are formed from different well-order relations (as described above) but with same order-type $\alpha$. Now while comparing the values of two different functions $I_1(x)$ and $I_2(x)$ let $a$ denote the smallest value for which $I_1(a) \neq I_2(a)$. Now we write $I_1 < I_2$ for two such functions iff $I_1(a) < I_2(a)$.

Now somewhat analogous to what you quoted, we could try to define the "smallest" function $I$ that describes the well-order relation for $\alpha$. But a closer examination will show that such a function $I$ is not well-defined. By contradiction, suppose there was such a function $I_{min}$. If $I_{min}$ indeed gives the description of some well-order relation for $\alpha$ then there must be some smallest value $a$ for which $I_{min}(a)\neq 0$. It is easy to see that one can describe a new function $I$ such that $I<I_{min}$ by "setting" it to have the property that $I(a)=0$.

While this isn't "exactly" as you described in quotes, the situation described above is quite similar. And illustrates that generally setting up such a simple property will not work to give a unique function (that "stores" all the information of well-order relation). As for the more specific description you gave in quotes, I think for $\omega \cdot 2$ and bigger values one will start to see that there is no such minimum real number (I might add a specific example later on).

Comment: I should clarify a few things. Firstly, can we be absolutely sure that it is impossible to obtain a method of representing well-orders as real numbers that will allow the given “definition” to work? Secondly, regarding the note “setting up such a simple property will not work to give a unique function” — but is it possible to define some more complex property that will allow to identify an unique real number that corresponds to a particular copy of $\alpha$?

Comment: I am not an expert on this at all, but this problem is "essentially" equivalent to giving (fundamental) sequences all the way up till $<\omega_1$. This thread may probably be of some relevance (specifically some parts in the answers): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883221.

Comment: @lyricallywicked Regarding my personal (and probably somewhat naive) understanding, once you have AC, then there also must exist a well-order of $\mathbb{R}$ and that, I "think", could then be used to give what you are asking for. However, a well-order of $\mathbb{R}$ in itself is not a simple matter. Some threads related to that which I found using a quick search:(i) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6501 (ii) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209033